# Enable remote errors with ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Normal ASP.NET (not core) applications could add this to the web.config to see errors from remote locations:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

It was helpful for when you could not login to the actual server to see what the error message was.

I can't seem to find the same setting in .Net Core.

**How do I turn on remote error messages in ASP.NET Core?**

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in the `Configure()` method of the `Startup.cs` class.

Changes are it's already there, but inside an `if (env.IsDevelopment())` statement, but you should be able to remove the if-statement and just leave it as is.